# How to allow CORS request from Javascript in Adobe Media Server

Tags: javascript, cors, http-live-streaming, adobe-media-server

I have a html page, calling HLS from javascript. Getting CORS error, of header "allow-control-allow-origin". I am using Adobe Media Server 4.5.
 
How can i allow CORS request from javascript?

Comment: i think you are using via RTMP right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Media Server use Apache HTTP Server. To enable CORS you need to add following line to Apache HTTP Server configuration file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "your_page_origin"
```

You need to replace "your_page_origin" with [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) of the page that will make requests, or with "*" to allow requests from any domain. Check [Enable CORS web site](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) and [Configuring Apache HTTP Server documentation page](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/config-admin/configuring-apache-server.html) for more information.

Also, you can use HTML `video` tag to embed HLS. When user agent makes request to `video` source it will not send `Origin` header by default, and it will not search for CORS-related headers in server response. You don't need to change server configuration in this case. Apple recommends to use `video` tag in their [introduction to HTTP Live Streaming Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> **Important:** Where possible, use the <video> tag to embed HTTP Live Streaming, and use the <object> or <embed> tags only to specify fallback content.

Check [How can I play Apple HLS live stream using html5 video tag thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434803/how-can-i-play-apple-hls-live-stream-using-html5-video-tag) for more information.

Comment: Also required to uncomment/add below line,

LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so