# Play Adobe media server in Asp.net core 2.2 web Application

Tags: asp.net, m3u8, adobe-media-server

I have web application with asp.net core 2.2. this application is a client for a Api server

i'm using adobe media server 5 for video streaming and my stream urls is like

this:http://localhost/hls-vod/sample1_150kbps.f4v.m3u8

I play that link with [hls.js](https://hls-js.netlify.com/demo/)

but i get this Error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost/hls-vod/sample1_150kbps.f4vFrag1Num0.ts' from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

follow solutions are not working for me :

https://community.adobe.com/t5/media-server/how-to-allow-cors-request-from-javascript/td-p/8691655

[How to allow CORS request from Javascript in Adobe Media Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158655/how-to-allow-cors-request-from-javascript-in-adobe-media-server)

**is there better solution for playing media server stream in asp.net core web applications?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was about my urls i will change slash or backslash

this work for some videos but other still not working and i found that

other video must be converted

> ffmpeg-20190709-5a481b1-win64-static