# FFMPEG RTSP IP Stream (H.264) convert to RTSP stream (MPEG-2)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, ip-camera, mpeg

I currently have an IP camera streaming video (RTSP) with H.264 encoding.

I want to use FFmpeg to convert this H.264 encoded stream to another RTSP stream but MPEG-2 encoded. How exactly do I do this? Which commands should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this. You may use `ffmpeg` to convert your RTSP-stream to MPEG-2 stream. Take a look at this answer it solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/41836896/2000107